# Connect Four - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, connect-four

I'm having serious problems with my jQuery homework (I'm a student and a JS beginner).

Basically the assignment is to create a Connect four game with jQuery using the MV(C) (we don't use the controller) schema.

The playing field is a 2D array and looks like this.

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , -
```

and the players play by pressing the columns (f.ex. Player 1 presses 3)

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , x , - , - , - , -
```

and the Player 2 presses 4

```
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , - , - , - , - , - 
- , - , x , o , - , - , -
```

and so on.

When the game is over the winning four letter should change to uppercase.

I'm stuck and don't really know how to go on so I created a GitHub repository with all the code.

https://github.com/VeronicaLeeds/connectfour

Basically it initializes the playing field and you can press the numbers but then the play() method won't work.

I don't know any other way to call the function from View.

I tried View().play , View.play() , play() ...
But there i always an error.

```
if (evt.which == 49) {
   View().play(1);
   return 1;
   console.log('1');
}
```

The play() function is in the View.js file.

Would be eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: You are encouraged to visit this link and learn more about how this community can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/tour  Currently your question does nothing more than describe your homework and link to a repository of code, and you are asking that we setup and debug and fix your code for you.  That's not what this community does.  It is expected that *you* debug your code.  If your code is doing something unexpected, when stepping through your code in a debugger where does that unexpected behavior first happen?  What specific operation is breaking?  What did you expect it to do?  Why?

Comment: Just a side note, `console.log('1');` will never be printed because you're returning 1 before. Try moving `console.log('1');` on top of `return 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little heads up, you should work on renaming your files to something significant. It's hard to find the relevant code when the names of some files are as vague as `js.js`.

That aside, your function `checkIfWon(arr)` in `js.js` uses the method `checkForFour()`, which takes in an array as a parameter and returns true or false based on whether 4 pieces from the same player have been detected.

Since it would be redundant to iterate twice over the same array, you could make `checkIfWon(arr)` return an empty array if no connect-4 was detected, and column (with the winning streak in uppercase) if there was a connect-4 detected.

For instance:

```
// Horizontal
var tempArrayHorizontal = new Array(7);
for (var row = 0; row <= 5; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col <= 6; col++) { 
        tempArrayHorizontal[col] = playFieldArray[col][row];
    }
    var result = checkForFour(tempArrayHorizontal);
    if (result !== []) {
        for (var col = 0; col <= 6; col++) { // we re-iterate the same way we did when you populated tempArrayHorizontal
            playFieldArray[col][row] = result[col];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and your `checkForFour` function:

```
function checkForFour(input) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === currentPlayer) {
            count++;
            if (count === 4) {
                // replace the 4 previous column to uppercase
                input.splice(i-4, 4, currentPlayer.toUpperCase(), currentPlayer.toUpperCase(), currentPlayer.toUpperCase(), currentPlayer.toUpperCase());
                return input;
            }
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

I haven't tested it, so you'll have to confirm on your end.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you. I made quite a few changes in the code. 
Do you know why in the model.js file in the event_listeners function the View().play() doesn't work?

Comment: what could be a possible solution?

Comment: Actually, I lied, that's not the problem. Put `var view;` at the top of your script, replace `View().play(1);` for `view.play(1)` and instantiate your view using `view = new View();` under `lib.View = View;` in  `model.js`.

Comment: Thanks this finally works. If you got any more time and motivation to give me more tips (there are still a TON of mistakes in the code) I would be forever grateful.